# Automate AWS SSM document execution

Tags: schedule, aws-ssm

I have an `AWS SSM document` shared from another account, to install a software on an `EC2 instance`. Since there are auto-scaled EC2 instances, depending on the demand, new instances spin up.

Requirement is to automate this document execution on all the SSM Managed EC2 instances every day at a specified time, so that no EC2 instance will be left out without the required software.

What are the ways I can use here? I tried using the `Run Command` feature, but the name of document does not show up in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSM State Manager to automate the execution of that SSM document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-state.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a Lambda function

- Fetch list of EC2 instances,
- use SSM (SendCommand) to run your document on each of the instances.

2. Set up a Cloudwatch Event to invoke Lambda function daily at desired time.